# Cannot access attribute from Angularjs directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I think I'm just doing something dumb here, but I want to access a custom attribute on an HTML element that I attached a directive to but it doesn't work. I've seen other folks use scope.$eval but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Here's what I tried (jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/u5d3gfny/1/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AngAttrTest">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>      

        <a href="#" id="my-modal" class="btn btn-success fcvt-btn-save" nextModalId="fileFormatModal" chain-modal>Continue</a>
        <div id="appendMe"/>

        <script>

            var app = angular.module('AngAttrTest', []);

            app.directive('chainModal', ['$document', function($document){

                return  {

                    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                        elem.bind('click', function() {
                            $('#appendMe').append("This works, ID: " + attrs.id + "<br/><br/>");
                            $('#appendMe').append("So does this, Class: " + attrs.class + "<br/><br/>");
                            $('#appendMe').append("But my custom Attribute nextModalId comes up undefined: " + attrs.nextModalId + "<br/><br/>");
                        });
                    }

                }
             }]);           

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried replacing my link function with this to no avial:

```
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.bind('click', function() {
                            var nextModalId = scope.$eval(attrs.nextModalId);

                        $('#appendMe').append("This works, ID: " + attrs.id + "<br/><br/>");
                        $('#appendMe').append("So does this, Class: " + attrs.class + "<br/><br/>");
                        $('#appendMe').append("But my custom Attribute nextModalId comes up undefined: " + nextModalId + "<br/><br/>");


                    });
                }
```

This seems like it should be really simple but I can't figure out what fool thing I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the directive is used as an attribute it must be declared in snake-case. To fix...

Change `nextModalId`:

```
<a href="#" 
   id="my-modal" 
   class="btn btn-success fcvt-btn-save" 
   nextModalId="fileFormatModal" 
   chain-modal>
    Continue
</a>
```

To `next-modal-id`:

```
<a href="#" 
   id="my-modal" 
   class="btn btn-success fcvt-btn-save" 
   next-modal-id="fileFormatModal" 
   chain-modal>
    Continue
</a>
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/36exuuk1/)

Comment: Yep, and thanks again. I shoulda known it'd have to be snake-case since everything else is :).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with elem.bind function not the directive. I changed the code this way:

```
        var app = angular.module('AngAttrTest', []);

        app.directive('chainModal', ['$document', function($document){

            return  {
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.bind('click', { id: attrs['id'], class: attrs['class'], nextModalId: attrs['nextModalId'] },  function(event) {
                        $('#appendMe').append("This works, ID: " + event.data.id + "<br/><br/>");
                        $('#appendMe').append("So does this, Class: " + event.data.class + "<br/><br/>");
                        $('#appendMe').append("But my custom Attribute nextModalId comes up undefined: " + event.data.nextModalId + "<br/><br/>");
                    });
                }
            }
         }]);
```